# Python Test Monkeypatch with Arguments

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I try to create a mock test with monkeypatch. I have a typical service-repository class.

repository_class.py

```
find_by_id(id):
   con.select(....);
```

service_class.py

```
get_details(id):
    some pre-process...
    item = repository_class.find_by_id(id)
    post-process...
    return result
```

then I try to create a mock test with mocking repository method under service:

```
def test_bid_on_brand_keyword(monkeypatch):
    mock_data = "abc"

    monkeypatch.setattr(repository_class, 'find_by_id', mock_data)

    ans = service_class.get_details(id)

    assert ans is not None
```

This doesn’t work. It tries to call real repository method. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`monkeypatch` couldn’t work for me. I used `@patch` or `with patch` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Return value should be an (mock) object, so i would do it like this

```
def test_bid_on_brand_keyword(monkeypatch):    
   monkeypatch.setattr(repository_class, 'find_by_id', lambda _:"abc")
   ans = service_class.get_details(id)
   assert ans is not None
```